# How to calculate daily profit based on the date in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to calculate daily profit based on the date. What formula should I use here? Thank you!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxfKy.png]

Comment: You state Google sheets in the title, but tag Excel. Sort out which is relevant.

Comment: thanks. I'm new here.

Comment: `SUMIF()` is the answer

Comment: I use importrange to import data (date, profit). One day I can receive 5 orders, another day 50 so I need to calculate it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:B}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''")
```